# Uri.MakeRelativeUri incorrectly handling ../

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, mono

I'm getting an incorrect path when using MakeRelativeUri. Now this could be an issue with Unity and mono or hopefully I'm just using it wrong or maybe there's actually a bug in .net. You'll have to forgive the elaborate example but this is what I have.

```
System.Uri fileURI = new System.Uri( "/Home/Folder1/Folder2/Folder3/Folder4/Folder5/Folder6/../../../../Folder7/Folder8/file.png" );
System.Uri rootURI = new System.Uri( "/Home/Folder1/Folder2/Folder3/../FolderA/." );
result = rootURI.MakeRelativeUri( fileURI ).ToString();
```

result in this case is `../../Folder4/Folder5/Folder6/../../../../Folder7/Folder8/file.png`

but it should be 
`../Folder3/Folder4/Folder5/Folder6/../../../../Folder7/Folder8/file.png`

It seems as though it is treating the ../ in the root path as a directory rather than an instruction to go back a directory. Can anyone confirm if thats the case?

Comment: Can you update sample so it compiles? (RootPath need to be absolute...)

Comment: Replaced the pseudo code with c# code

Comment: I should have payed more attention to tags - original code probably was fine. The code you've posted does not work on regular .Net (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32826283/not-getting-invalid-uri-exception-on-ideone), but seem to be fine on mono. Check if old similar question helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3692818/uri-makerelativeuri-behavior-on-mono

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've worked around this by passing the path strings through `Path.GetFullPath()` before passing them into the `Uri` constructor. That strips out the ../ correctly and this then works as you would expect.